# Google Maps iOS SDK and UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SDK in an iOS project.

I added `UIView` in `GMSMapView`. I want to handle a swipe on `UIView` and add to `UIView UIGestureRecognizer`, but the handler's not working when I do `UIView` on `GMSMapView`. I know what `GMSMapView` lock a `UIGestureRecognizers`. I use `consumesGesturesinView=NO`, but it didn't help.

How I can unlock `UIGestureRecognizer` in a `GMSMapView` subview? Thanks!

Comment: Google Map lock gesture recognizer on subviews, use touchesBegan, touchesMove and touchesEnd